# Swift macOS - find all files of a specific extension

Tags: swift, macos, file, directory

I need to find the names of all files that have the extension `.pub` in the path `~/.ssh`.

So in the end I need to have an array of names.

I solved it like this, I wonder if there is a possibility to write it in a better and more compact way as code.

```swift
func arrayFile(path: String, ext: String) -> [String] {
  guard let desktopPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.desktopDirectory,.userDomainMask,true).first else { return [] }
  let pathConfig = desktopPath.replacingOccurrences(of: "Desktop", with: path)
  let filemanager: FileManager = FileManager()
  let files = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: pathConfig)
  var array = [String]()
  while let file = files?.nextObject() as? String {
    if file.hasSuffix(ext) {
      let name = file.replacingOccurrences(of: ext, with: "")
       array.append(name)
    }
  }
  return array
}

let array = arrayFile(path: ".ssh/", ext: ".pub")
print(array)
```

Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: Why not start from the [home folder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1642807-homedirectoryforcurrentuser) rather than the Desktop folder. And in general you should work with URL's rather than string paths.

Comment: Then show me your solution?

Comment: You asked for some suggestions and I gave you some.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. FileEntry is a simple struct with a URL.

```
func directoryContents(justPlaylistFiles: Bool = true) -> [FileEntry] {
    guard let url = userSelectedFolderURL else {
        logger.error("userSelectedFolderURL: nothing is selected")
        return []
    }
    
    let keys: [URLResourceKey] = [
        .isReadableKey,
    ]
    
    let options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions = [
        .skipsHiddenFiles,
    ]
    
    do {
        let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url,
                                                                includingPropertiesForKeys: keys,
                                                                options: options)
        print("All files \(files)")
        
        if justPlaylistFiles {
            let playlistFiles = files.filter {
                ["m3u", "m3u8"].contains($0.pathExtension.lowercased())
            }
            let entries = playlistFiles.map { FileEntry(fileURL: $0) }
            return entries
        } else {
            let entries = files.map { FileEntry(fileURL: $0) }
            return entries
        }
    } catch {
        logger.error("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return []
}
```